# How to select all node that contain specific element among any child (i.e. child, grandchild, etc.) nodes

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<test>
    <a></a>
    <a><a1><c type="5"/></a1></a>
    <a><a2><a1><c type="5"/></a1></a2></a>
    <a><a2><a1><c/></a1></a2></a>
    <a><c type="6"/></a>
</test>
```

I want to select all `a` nodes that have `c[@type = '5']` among its children, or grandchildren, or grandgrand..children, i.e. anywhere in the hierarchy. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solution:

```
//a[descendant::c[@type = '5']]
```